# Batch clip DWG polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, batch, cad

I have about 170 DWG files that need to be clipped to their corresponding tile. Each tile is 14,000ft wide, 8,000ft height.

The grid:
[image]

Each DWG file overlaps the tile border by 800ft:
[image]

Unfortunately, each DWG file is in its own directory, so I'm not sure if that makes coding a batch clip more difficult. The file we're working with will always be named like "###_2ft.dwg"
[image]

So my question is: How can I efficiently clip these DWG's and output them as feature class files?

I have thought about creating a fGeoDB to copy each DWG polyline file into, however, for whatever reason when expanding the DWG layer it takes ~30 seconds to show the annotation, point, polyline, etc.

I've checked out some guides using iteration in ModelBuilder, but I can't get the same results. Specifically posts like [this](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/16316-Batch-Clip-in-modelbuilder). In that post, a user mentions constructing the geoprocessing command in notepad and using excel to help with filenames, but I'm not sure what the commands would be.

Answer (score 1):

It is straight forward.

I would do something like this.

Place all the folders into one folder on the C Drive called temp. Just do one dump. It will look through all your folders for CAD files.

The you can use model builder (recursive option) to find all the DWGS in the folder (it will search subfolders).

Use 'iterate datasets' in the model  with the folder hard coded.  See image
[image: setting]

Then using this model all the CAD will end up in the database.
[image: model]

I just tested and it worked

The final part is batch clip but I think you know that already it is the dwg to shape part that is causing issues.

Comment: This sounds like an awesome idea. The one question I have is - each folder has other DWG files, like in the example above, that will not be included in my clipping process. Is there a way (such as in the Wildcard) field to choose only those that fit the "###_2ft.dwg" naming convention?

Comment: Sure use a wild card just like you say. It is in the menu. I think it would be *_2ft in your case.

Comment: When I used this suggestion, it seems as thought the last processed DWG file is the only file in the database. It also seems like everything is being "indentified" in the "Iterate datasets" portion, but only the last DWG file is being used in the tool. Should it run all the way through and repeat each time instead?